# How to test dependency injection with annotations?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

In Spring Framework or Java EE there are annotation based Dependency Injection .

Normally you would do

```
class X
{
    Y var;

    public X(Y var)
    {
       this.var = var
    }
}
```

This is so easy to test and mock. You just instantiate class Y as you like for your test.

But how about this.

```
class X
{
    @Inject or @Autowired
    Y var;

    public X( )
    {

    }
}
```

How about annotation based Dependency Injection.
You have the same problem as with hard coded instatiation.
I have no possiblity to inject a mocked object as I could in the first code example. How can I test it ?

Comment: Umm... by refactoring your code to make it easy to test? This is precisely the reason why constructor injection is the recommended practice

Answer (score 0):

> I have no possiblity to inject a mocked object as I could in the
> first code example

Why is that?

```
@Component
class X {
    Y var;

    @Autowired
    public X(Y var)
    {
       this.var = var
    }


   @Component
   class Y {
  
   }
```

And then

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ApiControllerTest {
 
    @Autowired
    private X x;
 
    @Configuration
    static class Config {
 
        @MockBean
        private Y y;
    }
}
```

Comment: the only way now is with reflection . Using some other framework like Mockito as I understand

Comment: you mean how to do dependency injection without spring and annotations? Because you said dependency injection with annotations. Those annotations are from spring itself like `@Autowired` that you have